# How can we repeat the table row in jquery like angularjs does with ng-repeat?

Tags: jquery, angularjs-ng-repeat

How can we rpeat the table row in jquery like angularjs does with ng-repeat?

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="person in people">
        <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: look at the angular code to see how they are doing it

Comment: Perhaps you might find this plugin interesting https://code.google.com/p/widgets-js/wiki/Repeatable

Comment: There's a lot going on in angularjs: parsing the ng-repeat attribute to determine the property in question, parsing the rest of the template, creating the rows based on the template, using databinding principles to keep the results updated... Which parts are you interested in here?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422137/1271037

Answer (score 11):

You can achieve this using each() of jquery.

Step 1. 
Provided that you should have some js object structure

```
var people = {
 "persons" : [
  {"name":"ABC", "address":"XYZ"},
  {"name":"PQR", "address":"STO"},
  {"name":"LMN", "address":"POP"}
 ]
};
```

Step 2. Create html table element in which to create dynamic rows :

```
<table id="dynamicTable">    
</table>
```

Step 3. Generate table tr's dynamically using jquery's each() function and provided js object in Step 1

```
var inHTML = "";

$.each(people.persons, function(index, value){
    var newItem = "<tr><td>"+ value.name + "</td></tr>"
    inHTML += newItem;  
});

$("table#dynamicTable").html(inHTML); //add generated tr html to corresponding table
```

Following these steps dynamic table generation with repeated rows can be done using jquery.

Comment: Hey babtech, you can apply above steps to achieve functionality using Jquery. :)

Comment: @babtech, is it useful to you?

Comment: @babtech, Please accept the answer if its relevant to your question.

Comment: but we will not have two way binding in this case right?

Comment: @meShakti, correct but two way binding cannot be achieve with jquery in this case. We need to create customized binding for each row if required using jquery. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

look around the .each() function, i think you can do what you want with it.

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/