# achieving angular ng-repeat like feature in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs-ng-repeat

Im currently working on a code to achieve something like ng-repeat in angular. Basically a for-loop in html.
the code takes every element with the class "loop" and processes it with the information given through the "info" attribute. Here is the code :
HTML

```
<div class="loop" data-info="i in 1 to 10">
 -i-
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".loop").each(function(i){
 var loop_info=$(this).attr("data-info");
 var fin=loop_info.match(/(.*) in (\d+) to (\d+)/);
 var variable=fin[1],
 initial=fin[2],
 final=fin[3];
 var htm=$(this).html(),printed="";
 for(j=initial;j<=final;j++){
  var temp=htm;
  var r=new RegExp("-("+variable+")-","g")
  temp=temp.replace(r,j);
  printed+=temp;
 }
 $(this).html(printed);
});
```

Now i have also included the feature to replace the - variable - with the numbers.

Everything worked perfectly but when the loops are nested i.e

```
<div class="loop" data-info="i in 1 to 10">
 <div class="loop" data-info="j in 1 to 10">
  -j-
 </div>
</div>
```

it doesnt work on the nested loop ,i.e -j- doesnt get replaced with the numbers.
  I dont know why this is happening ,any help is appreciated.

Comment: `info` is an invalid attribute. Don't follow the same *mistakes*, use `data-info` instead.

Comment: @Roko thanks for pointing out the mistake i will edit the question rightaway

Comment: So, nested loops, the inner one operates `j` times in one `i`. So basically you should first check if any `data-info` element has other `data-info` children and act accordingly. `$(this).html(printed);` will destroy the child contents at the first `.each()`'s element iteration. Means the inner  `.loop` is destroyed/replaced and not accessible in the DOM cache at this point.

Comment: @Roko so is there a way to start the loop from child instead of the parent? or is there a way to check the child or grandchild of loop if it contains the loop class?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The replacement fails because the HTML is changed, and the next `.loop` reference that jQuery had collected for your `for` loop, no longer represents what it was before.

Instead, make your `for` loop go in reversed direction:

```
$($(".loop").get().reverse()).each(function(i){
    // etc...
```

Snippet:

```js
$($(".loop").get().reverse()).each(function(i){
  var loop_info=$(this).attr("info");
  var fin=loop_info.match(/(.*) in (\d+) to (\d+)/);
  var variable=fin[1],
      initial=fin[2],
      final=fin[3];
  var htm=$(this).html(),printed="";
  for(j=initial;j<=final;j++){
    var temp=htm;
    var r=new RegExp("-("+variable+")-","g")
    temp=temp.replace(r,j);
    printed+=temp;
  }
  $(this).html(printed);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="loop" info="i in 1 to 10">
    <div class="loop" info="j in 1 to 10">
      -i-:-j-
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Amazingly simple solution